# IOS microphone access not working while ongoing audio call

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, safari, permissions, microphone

In our web application on the browser (google-chrome, safari), I am accessing the user's microphone and video using `getUserMedia` Object:

```
   navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video:true })
      .then(function(stream) {
        console.log('permitted');
application logic
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log('Not permitted')
      });
```

Once both the permissions are approved by the user, we are starting live streaming of users' video along with his Audio. This streaming works fine except in one scenario on iPhone (IOS).

In the ongoing stream if the user receives the phone call and it starts answering, the ongoing streaming stops. Is it possible to access the microphone/video from the browser while ongoing audio call or does it blocked by Apple due to security reasons?

Comment: Have the same issue. Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @Wolf  Apple does not allow access to microphone when call is going on So we do not have solution for it